# How to change a togglebutton's state by clicking another togglebutton

Tags: android, android-togglebutton

So i have this situation where there are two togglebuttons on screen, and when i press togglebutton1, I want it to change the state of togglebutton 2, no matter the current state of togglebutton2, and when i press togglebutton2 i only want to change the state of that button itself.

I have already tried ToggleButton.setChecked, but this just changes a togglebutton's state from "true" to "false" or the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the state of the toggle button, use

```
toggleButton.toggle();
```